# Prove that $\operatorname{adj}(A^t)=(\operatorname{adj}(A))^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, transpose

I know this theorem is correct but I'm struggling to prove it formally:

For any square matrix A, $\operatorname{adj}(A^t)=(\operatorname{adj}(A))^t$.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean the matrix with $adj(A)·A=\det(A)$, that is, $adj(A)$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix?

Comment: Hi, no, I am familiar with the Theorem you provided. What I'm asking is different: The adjoint matrix of $A^t$ is equal to the transpose of the adjoint matrix of $A$.

Comment: What I mean is that your claim follows from my identity and $\det(A)=\det(A^t)$ and some commutativity, or that $adj(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$ where the coefficients come from the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Suppose that $A$ is nonsingular, then $\operatorname{adj}(A) = A^{-1}\det(A) \implies \operatorname{adj}(A)^T = (A^{-1})^T\det(A) = (A^T)^{-1}\det(A^T) = \operatorname{adj}(A^T)$. Now if $A$ is singular, let $A_t = A + tI, t\in\mathbb{R}$ be nonsingular, apply the identity to $A_t$, and use the fact that $\operatorname{adj}$ is a continuous function of $A_t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the property $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$ and the definition of $(\operatorname{adj}(A))_{ij}$ as the cofactor of the entry $(i, j)$ of matrix $A$. If not, a quick search can provide the necessary information.

Let's examine the entry at position $(i, j)$ in the adjoint of the transpose of matrix $A$:
$$\begin{align*}
(\operatorname{adj}(A^T))_{ij} &= (-1)^{i+j}\det(A^T(j\mid i))\\
&= (-1)^{i+j}\det((A(i\mid j))^T)\\
&= (-1)^{i+j}\det(A(i\mid j))\\
&= (\operatorname{adj}(A))_{ji}
\end{align*}$$

This demonstrates that the $(i, j)$-th entry of $\operatorname{adj}(A^T)$ is equal to the $(j, i)$-th entry of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$. In other words, we've established that $\operatorname{adj}(A^T) = (\operatorname{adj}(A))^T$.